# How many hugs a day should we give to obtain optimal positive effects?

Tags: well-being

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hug), hugging has health benefits. It stimulates the increase of oxytocin and reduces blood pressure. I have also heard varying advices about the number of hugs per day that you need; for example [here](https://greenwichpediatrics.com/12-hugs-a-day/). Is there a number of hugs a day that would be the most healthy? For example, 5 hugs a day, or 15?

My question is different from [this question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/26758/is-there-any-scientific-evidence-that-lack-of-physical-affection-has-adverse-eff) in the following way: my question is about what number of hugs gives the most health benefits, while the other question is about what number of hugs we need to avoid adverse effects.

Comment: Related: [Is there any scientific evidence that lack of physical affection has adverse effects in human adults?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/26758/7001)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any scientific evidence that lack of physical affection has adverse effects in human adults?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/26758/is-there-any-scientific-evidence-that-lack-of-physical-affection-has-adverse-eff)